# Allowing weak passwords for users

Tags: password

I just installed my brand new PI using the Wheezy image on Raspberry's site. Problem is it has such a strict password policy I cannot set it to anything less than 6 characters and even then it must have special characters.

How do I stop this strict password policy? I WANT a weak password so please no responses as to why this is a bad idea, closed network, doesn't matter.

Comment: This was very Googleable - don't forget that it's just Debian.

Comment: Why was this down voted?

Comment: I tried googling for 30 minutes before hand, couldn't find anyone in Debian that had that problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do the password change while super user

```
sudo -s
passwd <user>
```

Type and retype the password at the prompt and you are done (You need to substitute <user> with the actual name of the user you want to change the password). Once done, go back to user level with

```
exit
```

@Asclepius suggests a shorter solution with the oneliner `sudo passwd <user>`, you will have to insert your user password (unless your account is listed as NOPASSWD in the sudoers file) and then type and retype the password for the user. No need to `exit` as you will be taken back to your ususal privileges as soon the command is executed.

Comment: How about `sudo passwd user`?

Comment: @Asclepius It is a valid alternative, and I use it when I've similar tasks but, you have to type your password and then the user password. I think that elevate to superuser and then change the password is easier for a newbie than doing it in a single command. I will amend the response